# I'm having a little trouble understanding how to set a method that accepts a single int array parameter and returns nothing

Tags: c#, static-methods

Its for an assignment in my class where my prof. refuses to tutor or help his students so I'll preface this post with I have almost no clue what I'm doing. I have everything I need before this setup but I can't go further until I knock this part out. I need to write a static method that accepts a single int parameter and returns nothing. I've been scratching over it for almost 2 hours just staring at my screen and scrolling through my notes to find something that may help.

I haven't tried anything yet as there isn't anything in my notes even similar to or close to what I need this to do.

Comment: _"how to set a method that accepts a **single int array parameter** and returns nothing"_ _" I need to write a static method that accepts a **single int parameter** and returns nothing"_ - so what it should be array or not?

Comment: You can try looking in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) or maybe even better - [in this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods)

Comment: It needs to accept an array and loop through the array displaying the values saved in the array

Comment: return nothing - `void`. Docs for arrays are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/). Check out the links I provided in the comments and if you still have questions - feel free to ask.

Comment: Neither of those really help me understand what I need to do. They told me how to create a method but not really how to make one loop and accept an array as a parameter

Comment: Start from declaring a method which accepts array of `int` and returns nothing. The provided links should be more or less enough for that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your problem but in C# the address of array is passed So, if a function does not return anything that does not mean that any operation can't be performed on the array inside the function.

```
    int[] myArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    MyMethod(myArray);


    public static void MyMethod(int[] myArray)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(myArray[i]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: this helped a lot I just have an error now saying not all code paths return a value

Comment: I fixed the error. You are awesome man I appreciate it.